# Multiple connections to one com port c#

Tags: c#, serial-port

I know that there is similar question answered, but the answer doesnt satisfy me.

At first i will explain my situation so that you understand, why i really need to communicate one com port twice.

I have to communicate with microcontroller by COM port. This microcontroller passes my messages to some devices. But it also provides transparent communication with some other controller. Working with this controller is quite difficult, but there are dlls provided for c# by producer. The problem is, this libraries make communication with chosen com port(in a way i cannot control), so that i dont have access to this com port later (it makes communicating with other devices impossible).

Is it possible to communicate to same com port twice? If it isnt, i will have to forget about provided library and write some code closer to metal, which will cost me a lot more time.

Comment: Why can't you write a wrapper around the port?  Or, use one of the virtual serial port drivers to duplicate it?  http://www.eltima.com/products/vspdxp/

Comment: You can consider putting the communication with the vendor's DLL in a separate executable, that you launch, and terminate when you need to talk to this other microcontroller. It should relinquish control over the port when the process is terminated. But I would rather buy an extra USB to RS232 adapter and forget about it.

Comment: This takes a different kind of metal.  Use lead and solder iron, tap off the TxD + GND signals to another serial port, the RxD + GND signals to a third.  Filter drivers that snoop on the serial port driver traffic are available as well, you'll need to go shopping for that.